# Relations between elements and eigenvalues of symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I encountered this problem while reading Titu's Linear Algebra book and have no clues how to start to solve this. Any helps is appreciated.

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a symmetric matrix. Let $\lambda_1, \dots , \lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues (counted with multiplicities) of $A$. Prove that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^2_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda^2_i.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(A^t B)$, this is called the Frobenius inner product. And by elementary computation, we see that $\langle A, A \rangle = \sum a_{ij}^2$. Now, as $A$ is symmetric and real we can apply the spectral theorem to write $A = PDP^t$ where $P^t=P^{-1}$ and $D$ is diagonal. Of course, the entries on the diagonal of $D$ are precisely the eigenvalues of $A$. Now, we compute as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum a_{ij}^2 &= \langle A, A \rangle\\
&= tr(A^tA)\\
&= tr((PDP^t)^t (PDP^t))\\
&= tr(P D^t P^t P D P^t)\\
&= tr(PD^2 P^t)\\
&= tr(D^2)\\
&= \sum \lambda_i^2.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: is there any other method? The use of Frobenius inner product is a bit too tricky for me, thanks.

Comment: I can't say I can think of another method off hand. Is there any particular step you're unsure about? It's not important that this is an inner product, you only need properties of the trace.

Comment: No, your solution is very cleary, and I have known a bit about the properties of trace already though, thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help!